# Unicode conversation in SQL Server Express 2012

Tags: sql-server, database, unicode, procedure

I am having trouble with unicode.  here is the my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertReminder]
    @userId nvarchar(50),
    @reminderText nvarchar(250),
    @createDate nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [095_user_reminder] (userId, "reminderText", createDate) 
    VALUES (@userId, @reminderText, @createDate)
END
```

i try to insert to database "Azərbaycan" .  but it insert like "Az?rbaycan".

How can i resolve this? Thanks...

Comment: Can you show the call to the stored procedure? Also why is `"reminderText"` in double quotes?

Comment: What is the collation for the table you are trying to insert into?

Comment: I actually solved it by typing N before the variable.